# Посимвольное чтение строки между нужными символами

Tags: c++, строки

задача написать программу, вынимающую вот таким вот образом в частном случае именно из таких строк именно эту последовательность.

Есть массив:

```
>;2;<;[,1,] - массив
1 2 3 4 5 6 - номера только для описания списка ниже
```

1. Откуда читать
2. номер символа от начала строки
3. до куда читать (до первого встречного символа)
4. Откуда читать
5. Номер символа от начала строки
6. до куда читать (до первого встречного символа)

Алгоритм такой:

1. Читаю посимвольно строку.
2. Ищу вторую скобку '>' (номер (char_num - это сколько раз символ встречаеnся от начала строки и сам символ  - все задается в конфиге)
3. Нашли символ читаем до другого символа, также задающегося в конфиге

Вопрос: как изменить текущий код чтобы прочитать то что внутри []

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    char char1 = '>';
    char char2 = '<';
    int char_num = 2; // > от второй скобки в строке
    char char3 = '[';
    char char4 = ']';
    int char_num1 = 1; // от первой скобки '[' встречается в строке первый раз
    unsigned int position = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int start_pos = 0;
    int end_pos = 0;
    std::string l_string = "";
    std::string r_string = "";
    int i=0;
    std::string verylongStr("<tr><td>Test_Value</td><td>234 [344]</td>");
    for (int k = 0; k <=1;k++){
        do {
            start_pos = verylongStr.find(">", start_pos+i);
            i++;
        } while (char_num > i);
        std::cout << "start_pos " << start_pos << std::endl;
        end_pos = verylongStr.find("<", start_pos);
        std::cout << "end_pos " << end_pos << std::endl;
        std::string sb = "";
        sb = verylongStr.substr(start_pos, end_pos-start_pos);
        std::cout << sb << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Результат работы программы:** >Test_Value

**Хотелось бы:** Test_Value,344

Comment: используйте функции-члены класса  string, чтобы найти позиции символов и  по этим позициям  получить подстроку  (substr).  Изучайте все возможности  string, и для вас все будет легко

Comment: Поменял, все равно получатся только первую сделать...

Comment: А есть описание конечной задачи, которую надо решить? Просто вот это копошение в непонятном коде и попытки что-то подмазать там, не понимая сути - это путь в Адъ отчаяния и депрессии, иногда в запой

Comment: @wirtwelt добавил вначало.

Comment: Вы просто описали то, что делается в коде. Описание задачи - это что в итоге надо получить, чего добиться. В примере у вас HTML, возможно вы решаете задачу парсинга HTML. Вряд ли у вас стоит задача написать программу, вынимающую вот таким вот образом в частном случае именно из таких строк именно эту последовательность. А вообще большинство задач по парсингу, где известен формат входа, решаются через regexp просто, быстро и изящно.

Answer (score 1):

Не сказал бы, что это длинная строка, ну да ладно:

```
std::string verylongStr("<tr><td>Test_Value</td><td>234 [344]</td>");
size_t k1 =  verylongStr.find_first_of('/');
while (!isalnum( verylongStr[k1]) ) --k1;
size_t pos1 = verylongStr.find_first_of('[');
++pos1;
size_t pos2 = verylongStr.find_first_of(']');
string s1 = verylongStr.substr(0, k1);
size_t k2 = s1.find_last_of('>');
++k2;
string res = verylongStr.substr(k2, k1 - k2) + verylongStr.substr(pos1, pos2 - pos1);
cout << res;
```

Старайтесь самим понять код, т. е. оставляю  для вас работу